# Can you make razercfg apply settings on startup?

Tags: mouse

I am using razercfg to set the DPI lower on my Death Adder Chroma.

It works fine, but has to be opened and set on ever bootup.

Im wondering if theres a way to force a profile on startup so i can forget about it?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Razercfg comes with a command-line configuration tool. I have a Deathadder too, and the configuration is resulotion number 1 for example. (There are 5 in total, so you can change 1 to whatever you want)

The command is:

```
razercfg -r 1
```

This will use the default profile and the default mouse, so if you have several profiles or several razer devices you will have to take a  look at `razercfg --help`.

To set it to execute on startup you probably have a way in your window manager, for example in XFCE you have `Settings Manager -> Session and Startup` where you can add a startup script.

Comment: Thanks can you provide any further details on the startup script? Im a Ubuntu noob and its a little beyond me currently!

Comment: @infernouk what ubuntu are you using? and if you are an "ubuntu noob" I guess you didn't switch to another window manager, but if you did, to which one?